# in python; convert list of files to file like object

Tags: python, text

Er, so im juggling parsers and such, and I'm going from one thing which processes files to another.

The output from the first part of my code is a list of strings; I'm thinking of each string as a line from a text file.

The second part of the code needs a file type as an input.

So my question is, is there a proper, pythonic, way to convert a list of strings into a file like object?

I could write my list of strings to a file, and then reopen that file and it would work fine, but is seems a little silly to have to write to disk if not necessary.

I believe all the second part needs is to call 'read()' on the file like object, so I could also define a new class, with read as a method, which returns one long string, which is the concatenation of all of the line strings.

thanks,
-nick

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) implements (nearly) all stdio methods. Example:

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> StringIO.StringIO("hello").read()
'hello'
```

[cStringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO) is a faster counterpart.

To convert your list of string, just `join` them:

```
>>> list_of_strings = ["hello", "line two"]
>>> handle = StringIO.StringIO('\n'.join(list_of_strings))
>>> handle.read()
'hello\nline two'
```

Comment: Oh great, that does it. 

I also did it the hard way, which also worked, StringIO looks better.

    class linesConverter:
        def __init__(self, input):
            self.buff = ""
            for line in input:
                self.buff += line
                 
        def read(self, n):
            a = self.buff[0:n-1]
            self.buff = self.buff[n:-1]
                return a